# Is there a cleaner way to write this SQL where clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a large query with the below WHERE clause that I'm hoping may be written in a cleaner / possible more efficient way. Each combination is specific and needs to be accounted for. **EDIT** Per the first comment i have modified the question. Again this is a very small part of a much larger query, so I'm not quite sure if this is the right route to take.

**DB**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `querytest`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `querytest` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `querytest`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `table1`
--

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `col0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table1`
--

INSERT INTO `table1` (`col0`, `col1`) VALUES
(1, 'val1'),
(2, 'val2'),
(3, 'val3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `table2`
--

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `col0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table2`
--

INSERT INTO `table2` (`col0`, `col1`) VALUES
(1, 'val1'),
(2, 'val2'),
(3, 'val3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `table3`
--

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `col0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table3`
--

INSERT INTO `table3` (`col0`, `col1`) VALUES
(1, 'val1'),
(2, 'val2'),
(3, 'val3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `table4`
--

CREATE TABLE `table4` (
  `col0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table4`
--

INSERT INTO `table4` (`col0`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES
(1, 'val2', NULL, 'val3'),
(2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, NULL, 'val3', NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL, 'val3'),
(5, 'val1', NULL, NULL),
(6, NULL, 'val2', 'val3');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `table1`
--
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col0`),
  ADD KEY `col1` (`col1`);

--
-- Indexes for table `table2`
--
ALTER TABLE `table2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col0`),
  ADD KEY `col1` (`col1`);

--
-- Indexes for table `table3`
--
ALTER TABLE `table3`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col0`),
  ADD KEY `col1` (`col1`);

--
-- Indexes for table `table4`
--
ALTER TABLE `table4`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col0`),
  ADD KEY `col1` (`col1`),
  ADD KEY `col2` (`col2`),
  ADD KEY `col3` (`col3`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `table1`
--
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  MODIFY `col0` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `table2`
--
ALTER TABLE `table2`
  MODIFY `col0` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `table3`
--
ALTER TABLE `table3`
  MODIFY `col0` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `table4`
--
ALTER TABLE `table4`
  MODIFY `col0` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `table4`
--
ALTER TABLE `table4`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `table4_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`col1`) REFERENCES `table1` (`col1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `table4_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`col2`) REFERENCES `table2` (`col1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `table4_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`col3`) REFERENCES `table3` (`col1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT table4.col0, table4.col1, table4.col2, table4.col3

FROM table4

LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.col1 = table4.col1

LEFT JOIN table2
ON table2.col1 = table4.col2

LEFT JOIN table3
ON table3.col1 = table4.col3

WHERE 
(
    (
     table1.col1 = 'val1' 
     AND 
     table2.col1 = 'val2' 
     AND 
     table3.col1 = 'val3'
    )

    OR 

    (
     table1.col1 = 'val1' 
     AND 
     table4.col2 IS NULL
     AND 
     table4.col3 IS NULL
    )

    OR 

    (
     table1.col1 = 'val1' 
     AND 
     table2.col1 = 'val2'
     AND 
     table4.col3 IS NULL
    )

    OR 

    (
     table1.col1 = 'val1' 
     AND 
     table4.col2 IS NULL
     AND 
     table3.col1 = 'val3'
    )

    OR 

    (
     table4.col1 IS NULL
     AND 
     table2.col1 = 'val2' 
     AND 
     table4.col3 IS NULL
    )

    OR

    (
     table4.col1 IS NULL
     AND 
     table4.col2 IS NULL
     AND 
     table3.col1 = 'val3'
    )

    OR

    (
     table4.col1 IS NULL
     AND 
     table2.col1 = 'val2' 
     AND 
     table3.col1 = 'val3'
    )

    OR

    (
     table4.col1 IS NULL
     AND 
     table4.col2 IS NULL
     AND 
     table4.col3 IS NULL
    )
)
```

**EXPECTED DATA**

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | val3 |
| 5 | val1 | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | NULL | val2 | val3 |

Thank You!

Comment: you should definitely provide some sample data for us to work off, and clearly indicate what expected results should be. Without the sample data, I think you're going to get a lot of misunderstandings.
For example, you don't even explain how the 4 tables you talk about are joined (if at all) .. and the only answer provided only tries to answer for 1 table .. not 4 ... so clearly not working :)

Comment: Modified per your suggestion. Just not quite sure if it will help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the output for `explain format=tree select ......`  to your question?   Because for determining **efficient** you need some explaining.

Comment: What output did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Ok . so yes, it helps immensely ... and yes, your logic can be greatly simplified.  For something like this, it's usually best to pull all possible values into a list so you can visualize (assuming not too many, there isn't - you just have 8 combinations).
Looking at those 8 combinations, the logic is pretty straight forward:
Each of the 3 columns (ie col1, col2 or col3) can either be their matching value (ie col1 = val1, col2 = val2, col3 = val3) .. or NULL.  And they can be in any combination of those values, or NULL ..

So we can greatly simplify the logic by using COALESCE function (as I recall somebody initially suggested - but didn't have it on all tables ;) ) ..

so try this query:

```
SELECT table4.col0, table4.col1, table4.col2, table4.col3
  FROM table4
      LEFT JOIN table1
         ON table1.col1 = table4.col1
      LEFT JOIN table2
         ON table2.col1 = table4.col2
      LEFT JOIN table3
         ON table3.col1 = table4.col3
  where coalesce(table4.col1,'val1') = 'val1'
    and coalesce(table4.col2,'val2') = 'val2'
    and coalesce(table4.col3,'val3') = 'val3'
order by col0
/
    



      COL0 COL1   COL2   COL3  
---------- ------ ------ ------
         2
         4               val3  
         5 val1                
         6        val2   val3  

4 rows selected.
```

In each case, it takes the col, and if it's NULL, it will "treat it" like the value it wants.

One stipulation on this .. usually using a function on a column likes this prevents indexes from being used, so watch performance with consideration to size of you tables.
Alternatively, the where clause might also be written:

```
where ( table4.col1 = 'val1' or table4.col1 is null )
  and ( table4.col2 = 'val2' or table4.col2 is null )
  and ( table4.col3 = 'val3' or table4.col3 is null )
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: `"table1.col1" can logically be replaced with "table4.col1" without changing results of the query.`  this is not true, because it is a LEFT JOIN.  When the record in table1 is not found, Table1.col1 will be NULL and Table4.col1 still has a value.

Comment: True, that's fair .. it's kind of why I was suggesting they could go with logic on the table4 side ... but you're right .. so let me tweak answer a bit to fix that .. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Move the condition into the join:

```
SELECT table4.col0, table4.col1, table4.col2, table4.col3
FROM table4
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.col1 = table4.col1
  AND table1.col1 = 'val1'
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table4.col2
  AND table2.col1 = 'val2'
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.col1 = table4.col3
  AND table3.col1 = 'val3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your solution will return all rows not the rows filtered from the WHERE clause in the original SQL. Any idea how to modify?

Comment: @teamdane All `col1` are defined as `not null`. Please explain why you have code `where table1.col1 is null` etc when that is clearly impossible.